# Entity Framework: Self Referencing DbSet, A referential integrity constraint violation occurred

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I have a WPF application with a tree list containing the following category class.  The tree list allows you to create new categories and set the parent category, however, when I try to set the parent category and save, I get this error:

A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property value(s) of 'Category.Id' on one end of a relationship do not match the property value(s) of 'Category.ParentCategoryId' on the other end.

I have tried to create a unit test and manually enter the values as to ensure it was not a databinding problem to the tree list.  I have narrowed it down to the way the classes are designed, but I don't understand exactly why I'm getting this issue.
[Here is a picture of the tree list if you want to see what I'm trying to accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rh2lF.png)

Many of my view-models derive from the save viewmodelbase with a similar save method, so I'm confused as to why their foreign keys will save but the category parent causes an error.

```
   public class Category : BaseDbClass
{

    public string CategoryName { get; set; }


    public Category ParentCategory { get; set; }
    public List<Category> SubCategories { get; set; }

    public int? ParentCategoryId { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return CategoryName;
    }
}
  public class BaseDbClass : ICheckTheDirty
{
    [NotMapped]
    public bool IsDirty { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public BaseDbClass()
    {
        DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
        DateUpdated = DateTime.Now;
        UserWhoUpdated = Environment.UserName;
    }


    public void ItemChanged()
    {
        IsDirty = true;
    }

    public void ItemSaved()
    {
        IsDirty = false;
    }


    public string UserWhoUpdated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateUpdated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

This is the method I have to save the category in the viewmodel:

```
 using (ProductContext db = new ProductContext())
        {
            foreach (var category in ItemsCollection)
            {
                if (category.IsDirty)
                {
                    db.Entry(category).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    category.ItemSaved();
                }
            }
            var s = await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            MessageBox.Show(s.ToString());
        }
```

Here is the xaml code to see how it is set in the view

```
<dxg:GridControl Grid.Column="0" EnableSmartColumnsGeneration="True" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsCollection}"
                                       SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
                <dxg:GridControl.View>
                    <dxg:TreeListView AllowPerPixelScrolling="True" ShowTotalSummary="True" KeyFieldName="Id"
                                          ParentFieldName="ParentCategoryId" />
                </dxg:GridControl.View>
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="CategoryName" IsSmart="True" />
                <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="ParentCategory" IsSmart="True">
                    <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                        <dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsCollection}" />
                    </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                </dxg:GridColumn>
            </dxg:GridControl>
```

The grid control comes from devexpress.  it uses the parentcategoryid

Comment: Most likely `ParentCategory` and `ParentCategoryId` properties are out of sync. Which one is bound to the UI?

Comment: I've edited to add how the ui is bound.  It is bound by the id properties

Comment: I don't think so. `FieldName="ParentCategory"` means the combo box is modifying the `ParentCategory` property, not the `ParentCategoryId`. Try setting `category.ParentCategoryId = category.ParentCategory?.Id;` before doing `db.Entry(category).State = EntityState.Modified;`

Comment: That seemed to fix it.  I guess I didn't notice that.  Shouldn't entity framework look at the navigation property and set the id on save?  That fixed it but I don't understand why.  Thank you very much.

Comment: It will in case the entity is loaded from the db in the context. But you are simply saying hey,  here is the entity populated with data and I'm telling you it's modified. And since you have 2 properties representing one and the same thing, it doesn't know which one is correct, hence the exception :)